# How to ensure that data will be saved before android kills a process

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

In Android it is generally a good practice to perform no database operation (or at least complex ones) in UI-Thread.  I have an activity with a complex form and I want to ensure that all data is saved when the activity goes in the background (e.g. the user presses the home button or a phone call comes in). In the activity’s onPause()-method I can start an AsyncTask which stores the data in database but I can never be sure that the task finishes successfully because android can kill the process before the task finished because the activity and the whole app is in background.

I can save data synchron in the onPause-method but then it’s possible to run in to an ANR.
I know that Android restores the views after the activity was killed but this works only correct when View Ids are unique. I have a lot of programmatically added Views where I cannot ensure the Id’s uniqueness and to use the saveInstanceState-functionality is nearly impossible because I have to save very complex models.

Is there any possibility to ensure that data will be saved before android kills a process without doing it in the UI-Thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created an application once where I had similar data consistency concerns. What I did there is delegate the storing of the data objects to a Service I created just for that purpose. Although this makes the starting/stopping/initialization of your Activity a lot harder (once the activity is started again, you will have to wait for the service to complete its previously started save action), this was the only "Android" way I could think of to deal with this problem.

Comment: According the Android api doc is less likely but also possible that a service will be killed. Ok, I can try to restart the service but to ensure that data will be saved I could run in to an endless cycle (I admit that is very unlikely but not impossible). At the moment the only way to store data and to be sure it's saved in any case is to do it in UI-Thread being a really awful app design

Comment: I totally agree with you observation about the worst-case scenario of Android deciding to kill your app even though it is hosting a service. This is possible, but at the same time (as you mention) highly unlikely. Storing data on the UI thread will actually NOT ensure that is is being saved, because after a few second the user may be presented with an ANR message. When he then decides to kill your app, it will go down immediately, without even finishing your save action.

Comment: By the way, what about these stories: the user decides to shut down his phone, while your service is storing data. Will you take a wake-lock to prevent this? And even with all this stuff in-place: what will you do in case the battery dies completely? I give these observations to make one point: how sure do you want to be? You should always analyze the trade-off between having done "enough" and doing "too much" to prevent data loss. How critical is the data you're handling? IMO delegating to an AsyncTask is still quite dangerous, but delegating to a Service is quite safe.

Comment: Thank you for your last comment, I think it’s summarizes the whole issue very well.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into using a service for that if you are afraid that the system kills your background-processes before they are completed. This might be over-kill, but will definitely work as expected =) Just google "Android Service Tutorial" if you are unsure how to use them.

-Services won't be killed unless you want them to!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, if you're running an `AsyncTask` in `onPause()`, Android can kill your applications's process without waiting for the worker thread to finish. But it won't kill the process if there's a running `Service`. So a nice solution here is to implement database synchronization logic using an `IntentService`.

Comment: Android kills every `Service` after 30 minutes and restarts it. Atleast, that's what I have noticed. If the `Service` is using cached data which is in memory to for example sync with an external source, will your solution still be valid?

Comment: @MartijnVanMierloo, IntentService isn't a good solution for a task that's supposed to run more than 30 minutes.

Comment: @Egor, actually if you ask me it is a total flaw of Android to kill services every 30 minutes. Moreover, it is even in conflict with the documentation on Services. In my opinion an IntentService is just as good a solution as any other Service (which other mechanism would you choose otherwise?) for tasks that need to run for an arbitrary amount of time (including 30+ minutes). Now I know you can start a Service with "foreground" priority, but that would seem to me more like implementation placebo than conceptual difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same question here, when to save data: while the user completes a form or when the activity pauses. Also we must take into consideration screen rotations or other events that might result in data loss.

Here is what I found on the [Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):

> For content provider data, we suggest that activities use a "edit in
> place" user model. That is, any edits a user makes are effectively
> made immediately without requiring an additional confirmation step.
> Supporting this model is generally a simple matter of following two
> rules:
>
> - When creating a new document, the backing database entry or file for
>   it is created immediately. For example, if the user chooses to write a
>   new e-mail, a new entry for that e-mail is created as soon as they
>   start entering data, so that if they go to any other activity after
>   that point this e-mail will now appear in the list of drafts.
> - When an activity's onPause() method is called, it should commit to the backing
>   content provider or file any changes the user has made. This ensures
>   that those changes will be seen by any other activity that is about to
>   run. You will probably want to commit your data even more aggressively
>   at key times during your activity's lifecycle: for example before
>   starting a new activity, before finishing your own activity, when the
>   user switches between input fields, etc.
>
> This model is designed to
> prevent data loss when a user is navigating between activities, and
> allows the system to safely kill an activity (because system resources
> are needed somewhere else) at any time after it has been paused. Note
> this implies that the user pressing BACK from your activity does not
> mean "cancel" -- it means to leave the activity with its current
> contents saved away. Canceling edits in an activity must be provided
> through some other mechanism, such as an explicit "revert" or "undo"
> option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a backgrounds service daemon with a notification to make sure your data is saved and shut down the service and notification as soon as the data is saved. The notification will be shown until the background service is running as it is mandatory to show services of background service otherwise your application would crash.